# Is it possible to add prefix to a column value after n lines of characters

Tags: mysql

If I have a column value 00001Document. I want this to have 00001-Document and it goes on as 00002-Document,00003-Document in all rows. I want to add - after 5 characters in all my columns.

Comment: So we know what you want, tell us what you have tried in order to achieve this

Comment: Sounds like a DB Design error. If you want the user to see `00001-Document` that does not mean you need to store that in a column. I suggest you seperate the numeric and the text into 2 columns and then if required concatenate them in a query code or in the application code (Presentation Layer)

Comment: i have to store that in the column. and the value before prefix can be text as well so i can not separate them by the numeric and text. i want to separate them after 5 lines of characters and add a prefix to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could  try

```
select concat(left(mycol, 5), '-', right(mycol, length(mycol)-5))
```